# Qt5 QML, when to use a ColumnLayout vs Column?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

For example, this works:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    function thingWidth()
    {
        return width*80/100
    }

    Column
    {
        spacing: 10;
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Thing { color: "red"; width: thingWidth(); }
        Thing { color: "yellow"; width: thingWidth();  }
        Thing { color: "green"; width: thingWidth();  }
    }

}
```

But change `Column` to `ColumnLayout` and it doesn't (resizing window causes layout to go wrong).

any  help, thanks.

EDIT 1:

Here's also `Thing.qml` as requested,

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    property alias color: rectangle.color
    width: 50; height: 50

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectangle
        border.color: "white"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

It looks like my post is mostly code. Yes, nanny it does! that's because people post code on here.

Comment: Please either a) provide the code for `Thing`, or b) replace them with something we have access to, like `Rectangle`.

Comment: done. sorry about the nanny

Answer (score 13):

As from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html) of `Column`:

> Column is a type that positions its child items along a single column. It can be used as a convenient way to vertically position a series of items without using anchors.

Moreover, it eases transitions during insertion, deletion and so on. It also attaches [properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-positioner.html) to the items to give them notions about their positions.

On the other side, [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html) is the documentation of `GridLayout` (please, note that `ColumnLayout` is a convenience utility, but it is nothing more than a grid with one column, as from its [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html)).
It has a completely different set of properties, as well as attached properties, completely oriented to the arrangement of the items.

I guess anyway that the most interesting page from the documentation is [that](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-layouts.html) one.
I simply cite it:

> Positioner items are container items that manage the positions of items in a declarative user interface. Positioners behave in a similar way to the layout managers used with standard Qt widgets, except that they are also containers in their own right.
>
> Positioners make it easier to work with many items when they need to be arranged in a regular layout.
>
> Qt Quick Layouts can also be used to arrange Qt Quick items in a user interface. They manage both the positions and the sizes of items on a declarative user interface, and are well suited for resizable user interfaces.

Please, note that a `Column` is a `Positioner`, while a `ColumnLayout` is a `Layout`. When to use them depends mainly on your goal, as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As i understand it, Positioners like `Column` can be told the positions, but layouts like `ColumnLayout` have to calculate the position themselves. Setting the `width` inside a `ColumnLayout` is bad, but in a `Column` it's ok.

Comment: Within the layouts you have a lot of interesting attached properties liked `Layout.preferredwidth`. Please, see the linked documentation.

Comment: Layouts were added once Qt has to support screens with very different sizes, i.e. after the nokia age. Indeed you got the `fill` property which is lacking in the other implementation. That's also stressed in the documentation when it says that they are "well suited for **resizable** user interfaces"

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Right, the `fill` property of the layouts is pretty useful, indeed. Damned `Column`s!! :-)

Comment: When it comes to text dynamic layouting you won't use say `Column`s are so damned. Trust me. ;)

Comment: Does it mean that `Layout` is for resizing items, and `Positioner` only moves items but doesn't affect their size?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Not exactly, but it's a side effect you can exploit.

Comment: I think a link to the [Positioners and Layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-layouts.html) documentation will be useful here :)

Comment: @StefanMonov It's there, see the sentence _I guess anyway that the most interesting page from the documentation is that one_, Should I enlarge it over the word _documentation_?

Comment: "ColumnLayout is a convenience utility, but it is nothing more than a grid with one **row**"