# Qt5-QML: ColumnLayout is overwriting another ColumnLayout when in a nested loop

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

After successfully designing the layout of a small application from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023457/how-to-set-a-basic-gridlayout-with-buttons-groupbox-text-and-progressbar-in-qm) I am adding the logic of the events. I almost completed it but some events are not happening as I am planning. Below the logic and the full source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/signalsqml/src/master/) in case would like to verify:

**1)** As soon as I chose the robot to connect to as show below, It does show I am connecting, but I am not able to interact with the `QML` page at all and all actions are blocked. I think this could be due to the fact that I have 2 `ColumnLayout` and I think that one is overwriting the other but I am not sure why that is happening as I thought the logic was complete:

[image: choice]

[image: ColumnLayout]

**The expected result** would be that when I am connecting to the robot, the entire page works instead of being (or looking) disable.

Below the most important part of the code that composes the **Minimal Reproducible Example** with the problem:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtWebEngine 1.8
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 440
    height: 630
    title: qsTr("Conn")
    property Page1 page1: Page1 {}
    property Page2 page2: Page2 {}
    Component.onCompleted: {
        page1.selectDialog.connect(function()  {
            mystackview.push(page2);
        });
        page2.onButtonClicked.connect(function(buttonId) {
            page1.dialogId = buttonId;
            mystackview.pop();
        });
    }
    StackView {
        id: mystackview
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: page1
    }
}
```

**Page1.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

import QtQuick.Controls.impl 2.12  // for IconLabel
import QtWebEngine 1.8

Page {
    property int dialogId: -1
    signal selectDialog()

    function buttonClick(button)
    {
        button.text = qsTr("Connecting to %1...").arg(button.text);
        button.enabled = false;
        if (button.background && button.background instanceof Rectangle) {
            button.background.color = "green";
            button.background.gradient = null;
            button.background.visible = true;
        }
        if (button.contentItem && button.contentItem instanceof IconLabel) {
            button.contentItem.color = "white";
            button.contentItem.font.bold = true;
            button.contentItem.font.pointSize = 20;
        }
    }
    function buttonClearList(buttonClear)
    {
        buttonClear.text = qsTr("Clear List").arg(buttonClear.text);
        buttonClear.enabled = true;
        if (buttonClear.background && buttonClear.background instanceof Rectangle) {
            buttonClear.background.color = "red";
            buttonClear.background.gradient = null;
            buttonClear.background.visible = true;
        }
        if (buttonClear.contentItem && buttonClear.contentItem instanceof IconLabel) {
            buttonClear.contentItem.color = "white";
            buttonClear.contentItem.font.bold = true;
            buttonClear.contentItem.font.pointSize = 20;
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        // anchors.fill: parent
        // anchors.topMargin: 0 // margin from top of the page
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 5
        Button {
            id: button1
            text: "Select Robot"
            width: parent.width
            onClicked: selectDialog()
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.pointSize: 20
        }
        Button {
            id: dialogA
            text: "Freddie Mercury: Connected"
            visible: dialogId === 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.pointSize: 20
            spacing: 10
            onClicked: {
                buttonClick(this)
            }
            ColumnLayout {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.topMargin: 50 // margin from top of the page
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                spacing: 10
                GroupBox {
                    id: box1
                    width: parent.width
                    title: "Connection"
                    font.pointSize: 20
                    Layout.fillWidth: parent
                    spacing: 10
                    GridLayout {
                        width: parent.width
                        columns: 1
                        RowLayout {
                            id: row1
                            spacing: 200
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            Layout.fillHeight: false
                            Label {
                                id: textField
                                text: "Connection:"
                                font.pointSize: 15
                                Layout.fillWidth: true
                            }
                            Text {
                                id: connected
                                text: "Not-Connected"
                                color: "red"
                                font.pointSize: 15
                                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                                Layout.fillWidth: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    id: clist
                    text: "Clear List";
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    font.pointSize: 20
                    width: parent.width
                    onClicked: {
                        buttonClearList(this)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Page2.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Page {
    signal onButtonClicked(var buttonId)
    Component.onCompleted: {
        button1.clicked.connect(function() {
            onButtonClicked(1);
        });
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        id: mybuttons
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 5
        Button {
            id: button1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "Freddie Mercury"
            font.pointSize: 20
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have been trying very different combinations of locating the `ColumnLayout` in different places. But my doubt i: I already have a `ColumnLayout` and after that I have another `ColumnLayout`, and I think that they are overwriting each other.
However, from the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) and also consulting other [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560164/qt5-qml-when-to-use-a-columnlayout-vs-column) re is no problem in using it in a nested loop. 
The same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560164/qt5-qml-when-to-use-a-columnlayout-vs-column) talks about how a `Column` is a `Positioner`, while a `ColumnLayout` is a Layout.
I was sure I was using in the right way but something is missing. 
Please point out in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, thank you very much for reading my question, the **minimal verifiable example** can be found here [https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/signalsqml/src/master/](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/signalsqml/src/master/)

Comment: I also updated the question adding it so it is available

Comment: I have not asked you for a link, I have asked you for an MRE that by definition should be a code that should be in your question allowing you to make a copy-paste, then execute it and then reproduce your problem. I think that with your experience on this site you know what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, give me one minute

Comment: @eyllanesc, I updated the question with the MRE. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic design rule:** If the parent item is disabled the children too.

**Explanation:**

In your case, the ColumnLayout is the child of the Button and this is the container of the other items that are your children, so if Button is disabled by the previous ColumnLayout rule, it will also be, and consequently also the entire contents of the ColumnLayout.

**Solution:**

In your case it is not necessary for ColumnLayout to be the children of Button but it can be on the same level.

---

On the other hand you have other errors:

- If you are going to use Layout.XXX then you should not use the widths.YYY since they fulfill the same task but if you use both you can have problems since it can have an indefinite behavior since they will compete with each other.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

import QtQuick.Controls.impl 2.12  // for IconLabel

Page {
    property int dialogId: -1
    signal selectDialog()

    function buttonClick(button)
    {
        button.text = qsTr("Connecting to %1...").arg(button.text);
        button.enabled = false;
        if (button.background && button.background instanceof Rectangle) {
            button.background.color = "green";
            button.background.gradient = null;
            button.background.visible = true;
        }
        if (button.contentItem && button.contentItem instanceof IconLabel) {
            button.contentItem.color = "white";
            button.contentItem.font.bold = true;
            button.contentItem.font.pointSize = 20;
        }
    }
    function buttonClearList(buttonClear)
    {
        buttonClear.text = qsTr("Clear List").arg(buttonClear.text);
        buttonClear.enabled = true;
        if (buttonClear.background && buttonClear.background instanceof Rectangle) {
            buttonClear.background.color = "red";
            buttonClear.background.gradient = null;
            buttonClear.background.visible = true;
        }
        if (buttonClear.contentItem && buttonClear.contentItem instanceof IconLabel) {
            buttonClear.contentItem.color = "white";
            buttonClear.contentItem.font.bold = true;
            buttonClear.contentItem.font.pointSize = 20;
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 5
        Button {
            id: button1
            text: "Select Robot"
            width: parent.width
            onClicked: selectDialog()
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.pointSize: 20
        }

        Button {
            id: dialogA
            text: "Freddie Mercury: Connected"
            visible: dialogId === 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            font.pointSize: 20
            spacing: 10
            onClicked: {
                buttonClick(this)
            }
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            id: layout
            visible: dialogId === 1
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            spacing: 10
            GroupBox {
                id: box1
                width: parent.width
                title: "Connection"
                font.pointSize: 20
                Layout.fillWidth: parent
                spacing: 10

                GridLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    columns: 1
                    RowLayout {
                        id: row1
                        spacing: 200
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Label {
                            id: textField
                            text: "Connection:"
                            font.pointSize: 15
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                        }
                        Text {
                            id: connected
                            text: "Not-Connected"
                            color: "red"
                            font.pointSize: 15
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button {
                id: clist
                visible: dialogId === 1
                text: "Clear List";
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                font.pointSize: 20
                width: parent.width
                onClicked: {
                    buttonClearList(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```